# MVC RouteConfig vs URL rewrite (in Global.asax)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Myself and a colleague had a problem that we solved in two different ways.  But we don't know which is best.

We have a generic MVC page that is populated with specific data (widgets, content, etc) from a database.  The user enters a specific URL (user friendly, so trying to keep the query string disguised if we can help it).

Now, the generic page has to take this URL and use it to get the corresponding data from the database to generate a specific page.

Solution 1: In the `Global.asax` file rewrite the URL, basically creating a Querystring that the generic controller can understand.

Soloution 2: Use the `RouteConfig.cs` file to force all page requests to route to the generic controller, which then reads the URL.

Any ideas,

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a fixed structure to the URL? - if so I'd be going with option 2 but I would break the URL down in the RouteConfig so that all the parameters are passed to the controller as named parameters there would be no need to do it in the controller later (unless it's complex/variable)

Comment: There's little to no fixed structure to the URL.  We are developing an in house website CMS and can't know in advance what pages would go where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RouteConfig.cs is the cleanest way.

If you change your routing configuration, then by using `Url.RouteUrl` or `Url.Action` your generated Url's will update along with your routing configuration.